# HTTPS Request in Sails.js - Getting `Error: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established`

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, sails.js, httprequest

I'm trying to make an HTTPS request in Sails.js and getting an error:
`Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established`.

I think I'm missing SSL files to send but I'm not sure if I am, I'm not sure how to get them from the page.

I'm trying to make an HTTP request in Sails.js using the `request` library.

I downloaded a website's SSL certificate in Firefox (got only a single `.crt` file).

I put the file in Sails' `assets` directory.

I created a sails config SSL file at `config/ssl.js` and in there I exported the SSL certificate file from the `assets` directory.

I created a controller, imported the SSL config object and put it inside a request's `agentOptions` property.

Note: I do not have a sails `http` file. Do I need to have? It wasn't created when I created the app with `sails new <app name>`.

SSL certificate file path: `assets/wwwoldhealthgovil.crt`

SSL config file, located at `config/ssl.js` (is read correctly, was able `console.log` it in the controller):

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports.ssl = {
    ca: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/wwwoldhealthgovil.crt')).toString()
}
```

Controller, `InactiveDoctorsController`:

```
const request = require('request');

module.exports = {

  getInactiveDoctors: function(req, res) {

    var options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://www.old.health.gov.il/oskimbbriut/rufim/DoctorSearchNew.asp',
      qs: {
        p: '1'
      },
      headers: {
        "Remote-Address": "147.237.72.200:443",
        "Referrer-Policy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
        "Host": "www.old.health.gov.il",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,fi;q=0.8,sv;q=0.7,he;q=0.6,el;q=0.5",
        "Cookie": "wcag-cookie-temp-www.old.health.gov.il=true; ASPSESSIONIDACBTQQTR=NMGEOCKABNLNMJBPKLMKKADD; ASPSESSIONIDACDRQQSR=MIGKLOGBIIGHAGGICMICLJKP; ASPSESSIONIDCADDTSAB=GBNOMJIBBKGDNMKEJBCGCFPH",
      },

      agentOptions: {
        ca: sails.config.ssl.ca,
      }

    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);

      console.log(body);

    });
  },

};
```

What is missing/what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems quite too complicated what you are doing. When i moved to https, i didnt need to do anything inside sails code as i remember. Just with the nginx configuration and command line.

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything complicated, just download a page via HTTPS that has a TSL certificate.

Comment: So the page you are trying to read uses a cert from your local machine to identify you, like SSO or something?

Comment: It uses certificates, not form my local machine, but I downloaded them and am sending them from my local machine. It's standard TSL certificates.